# Error Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android-studio

I installed `Android Studio` for the first time, but it doesn't even start but gives me this error:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

I have installed Intel HAXM and enabled Intel Vitualization within the BIOS.

Comment: Fixed some spelling issues and improved formatting. Please check my changes, and see if they reflect your intend. And hint: English is mostly lower case. There is No Point in Making some Words use Uppercase, that only confuses your readers.

Comment: Same issue, did you ever resolve it?